# Highcharts series showing different data for 'column' and 'line' chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a higchart with two Y axis. Both are line chart for first and everything works fine. But when I change it to column chart for one Y axis item, the graph plotting in different way. There seems some points are missing. I have a button for toggling between 'column' and 'line' chart. upon clicking the button it shows different kinds of graph, even if the data are same for both. This is my javascript,

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/whjvj', function (dataSeries2) {
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/dfoin', function (dataSeries1) {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      yAxis: [{
          height: 250,
          gridLineWidth: 1,
          title: {
            text: 'series 1',
            style: {
              color: '#3eca4f',
            },
          },
        },
        {
          title: {
            text: 'series 2',
            style: {
              color: '#888f94',
            },

          },
          top: 300,
          height: 100,
          offset: 0,
        },
      ],
      series: [{
          name: 'Series 1',
          yAxis: 0,
          type: 'line',
          data: dataSeries1,
        },

        {
          data: dataSeries2,
          name: 'Series',
          type: chartTypeRenew,
          yAxis: 1,
        },
      ],

    });


  });
});
```

[And here is the fiddle of the same](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/30v2schq/)

Can anyone please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the series types the data grouping also changes, so that points are approximated differently. If you force data grouping to "Week" it will appear more similar (though it might be weird for some other time intervals).

Add this to each series to force "Week" data grouping ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrtcp3x1/)):

```
dataGrouping: {
    units: [[
        'week',
        [1]]
    ]
}
```

Or [see the documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.dataGrouping.units) for more details.

Comment: Thank you friend. Your answer helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

That issue is caused by `dataGrouping`. By default, `approximation` is different for `column` ('sum') and `line` ('average'). You can disable `dataGrouping` or set the same `approximation`.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataGrouping: {
            approximation: 'average'
        }
    }
},
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vy9e580s/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.dataGrouping.approximation

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was with the dataGrouping as you said. I set the units for the dataGrouping and everything solved.